# django cbv redirect to full url

Tags: django, django-views

What is the right way to handle short urls in CBV? 
By short urls I mean redirect from `site/page/pk/` to `site/page/pk/slug/`.

Currently I'm using a separate redirect view:

```
class PageRedirectView(RedirectView):
    pattern_name = 'display_page'

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):
        page = get_object_or_404(Page, pk=kwargs['pk'], is_live=True)
        kwargs['slug'] = page.slug
        return super(PageRedirectView, self).get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs)
```

where display_page is a name in urls.py:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]*)/(?P<slug>.*)/$', views.display_page, name='display_page'),
```

But I'm not sure it is the right way. Is there are special method in DetailView for such redirect?